# How can I add non-businessHours on fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

In my calendar, I would like to not see the events but instead have the range of the event greyed like what is not in the businessHours range.

For example, if I have those businessHours:

```
businessHours: {
  start: '08:00',
  end: '12:00'
}
```

and an event which starts at 10:00 and finishes at 11:00, I would like to have the exact same render as :

```
businessHours: [
  {
    start: '08:00',
    end: '10:00'
  },
  {
    start: '11:00',
    end: '12:00'
  }
]
```

Is there a way to add unavailable range of time like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using background events? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/

Comment: Never succeed to make them work like I want but I just made a function to go throught my events and create businessHours dynamically in function of my originals businessHours. Thank you